# How to shorten a URL in groovy?

Tags: encryption, groovy, sha256, hmacsha1

I have created a URL that consist of some parameter like client id , expiry date and so on. Among these parameters I have one parameter called "Signature" which is hmac encrypted to maintain the security. Now the final URL getting generated is of length greater than the column length in which it is supposed tobe stored. Changing the length of the DB column is not a feasible solution. Now how should i shorten the URL to store it in the column?

The first approach i took was to also encryt the generated URL using HMAC encryption. But as this generated URL is to be used by a third party application and that HMAC encrypted values are impossible to be decryted to the original data . Now I am not sure how to store this URL in groovy file

Comment: How much shorter does it need to be? What is the length of URL versus the maximum length? What is the type of the database column?

Comment: maybe you don't need to store security part of URL?

Comment: James K Polk  : The maximum size of the column is 255 Varchar whereas the URL getting generated is 316(without encryption).The length getting generated would also depend on the data of the candidate we are using to create URL.

Comment: The URL needs to be stored in the DB with the secure part as well, as there is a third party application gonna use this URL to launch a test. There is no other way they can get the launch test URL.